# How to silent variable attributions (assignments)?

Tags: makefile

My makefile starts with something as

```
 myVar   := $$( etcExecute )
```

And it prints 10 times the `$$` line if I use `$(myVar)` 10 times in an event. For example this test prints twice:

```
 test:
         ls $(myVar)/1
         ls $(myVar)/2
```

**How to supress these ugly prints?**

There are a specific directive to silent only variable assigments?

Comment: Should you use `@ls $(myVar)/1` ?

Comment: Please show the actual output you see and explain clearly which parts of that output you don't want to see.  I don't understand what this is trying to do at all.  Why do you use `$$` in the assignment of `myVar`?  That seems very wrong to me, unless `etcExecute` is some command that you're running...??