# How to compare strings in a conditional assignment?

Tags: makefile

Is difficult to understand [this official guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html)... How to check string condition?

[This assign is working fine, but **is ugly**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63781809/how-to-silent-variable-attributions-assignments):

```
x := $$( if [ $(HOME) = "/root" ]; then echo "IS ROOT"; else echo "IS OTHER"; fi )
```

This is not working:

```
ifeq ($(HOME),"/root")
x = "IS ROOT"
else
x = "IS OTHER"
endif
```

---

`make --version` says:

```
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Try either removing the double quotes from around `"/root"` or adding them around `$(HOME)` (e.g. `"$(HOME)"` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write:

```
ifeq ($(HOME),"/root")
```

you're using the form (from the doc you cite):

```
ifeq (arg1, arg2)
```

and `arg1` is set to `$(HOME)` and `arg2` is set to `"/root"`.  Suppose the `HOME` variable is set to the path `/root`.

So, make will compare `/root` to `"/root"`.  Are these the same string?  No: one has quotes around it so they are not the same string.

You want to use:

```
ifeq ($(HOME),/root)
```